# Ebay API get list of transactions

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I want to fetch historical data for Transactions. I see that there is an API (https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/finances/resources/transaction/methods/getTransactions)

I want to fetch last 6 months data. I was wondering if that is supported by the API or not.

There is this paragraph in the API spec and it is confusing me a lot.

"Alternatively, the user could omit the ending date, and the date range would include the starting date and up to 90 days past that date, or the current date if the starting date is less than 90 days in the past."

Does this mean I can only fetch only last 90 days data? I want to fetch last 6 months data.

I do not have ebay developer account. they say it will take sometime and even after that I am not sure whether I can test this API to get last 6 months data.